# Strange problem about a function that gets the machine word

Tags: c

I wrote a function to get the machine word in C yesterday, but it seems that there is something wrong in it.

Here is the code:

```
unsigned machineword()
{
int i = 1;
unsigned temp;
while (temp > 0)
{
    i++;
    temp = (unsigned)(~0 >> i);
}
return i;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "machine word"?

Comment: `temp` is used uninitialized in your program. If you change the program by initializing it to `1`, then the program reaches an undefined behavior when it shifts `~0` by the int width you are trying to compute.

Comment: Do you mean the number of bits in an unsigned int? What problems have you got when you run the code?

Comment: If an int is `N` bits long, shifting it by `N` bits is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get the width of `unsigned int` is `(sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT`).

EDIT: as noted by pmg, you should be aware of the theoretical difference between the size an `unsigned` takes in memory and the number of bits available for computing with. Your original code tries to compute the latter, and so does the program below. The above trick computes the space occupied in memory.

It is not very convenient to compute this number with `>>` as it is forbidden in C to use `>>` with a number equal to or larger than the size in bits of the type you are shifting. You can work around this, if you know that `long long` is strictly larger than `int`, by computing with `unsigned long long`:

```
unsigned machineword()
{
  int i = 1;
  unsigned temp=1;
  while (temp > 0)
  {
    i++;
    temp = (unsigned)(((unsigned long long)~(0U)) >> i);
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Except that `unsigned` may have internal padding. You can rely on `#include <limits.h>` and the `UINT_MAX` macro though

Comment: @pmg Thanks for the edit. I did google `CHAR_BITS` before typing it in. The flaw in this line of reasoning is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I think not (can't come up with a reference or example now). I know `-1` works (represents `UINT_MAX`) irrespective of representation.

Comment: @pmg I have just found the confirmation that so does ~0U: "If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E." in 6.5.3.3

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to avoid the UB when shifting for too large value while keeping your structure is:

```
unsigned machineword()
{
   unsigned i = 0;
   unsigned temp = ~0U;
   while (temp > 0)
   {
      i++;
      temp >>= 1;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of bits, you can use `CHAR_BIT` or `UINT_MAX`.
The `CHAR_BIT` approach gives you the number of bits each value occupies in memory.
The `UINT_MAX` approach gives you the effective available bits.

*Usually both values will be the same*

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned tmp = UINT_MAX;
  int i = 0;
  while (tmp) {
      i++;
      tmp /= 2;
  }
  printf("value bits in a unsigned: %d\n", i);
  printf("memory bits in a unsigned: %d\n", CHAR_BIT * (int)sizeof (unsigned));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant now.